# ProgressBar in Android

Tags: android

How to implement a progress bar in this example?

```
package org.postandget;
import org.postandget.R;

public class main extends Activity {


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
             for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
                {
                        System.out.println(i);
                }

                }
 }
```

While the loop executing i have to show a progressbar. I have worked on few examples, but nothing got right. Can any one help me?

Comment: Have you read the official tutorial? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

It's pretty easy.

Comment: for that you have to use Asyntask concept refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: @parthi04 look this example this will very help you
[PROGESSBAR EXAMPLE](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/progressBarExample.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is simple example of `Progresss Dialog`

[Example 1](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog)

[Example 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)

**Code Snippet**

```
package org.postandget;
import org.postandget.R;

public class main extends Activity {
ProgressDialog bar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     new BackgroundTask().execute("Main");
 }
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String , Integer, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        bar = new ProgressDialog(main.this);
        bar.setMessage("Processing..");
        bar.setIndeterminate(true);
        bar.show();

    } 
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                {
                        System.out.println(i);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
           }    
                }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        bar.dismiss();
      }
}
}
```

Comment: cant get that right... can u able to implement in this code??

Comment: in this code.. progress bar s running mean while numbers are also printing.. but if i press back button then progress bar  goes off. but still the process which prints number s running..

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to deal with progress while performing a task is by implementing AsyncTask. It has the logic in place to perform a task in a background thread, while updating progress from the UI thread. Check the reference, and google for examples:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to this this kind of operation is by using AsyncTask.Use onPreExecute() to show your ProgressDialog, doInBackground to do your stuff and onPostExecute to dismiss your ProgressDialog. ---

http://brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/82805.aspx